# Unable to change SRC of an iFrame (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to changes the SRC of the iframe but whatever I tried, that I found on google, it's doesn't work.

```
<?php
$url = "test";
?>
<button onclick="parent.sendMeBack();">Click Me</button>
<iframe id="download_id" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.zone-telechargement.com/homep.html"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendMeBack(){
    document.getElementId('download_id').src = "./index.php";
}
</script>
```

Comment: elaborate .................please

Comment: The button doesn't work to redirect the iframe page to the new website..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three errors in your source.

- `parent` in the onclick won't work. Get rid of it.
- a button without a type is a submit button. That is, it will submit the page and reload it with the original src for the iframe. For a non-submit button, you need `type="button"` in the start tag.
- to get an element by ID in JavaScript, use `getElementById` (you forgot `By`).

```html
<?php
  $url = "test";
?>
<button type="button" onclick="sendMeBack();">Click Me</button>
<iframe id="download_id" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.zone-telechargement.com/homep.html"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendMeBack(){
    document.getElementById('download_id').src = "./index.php";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Info: i had to remove the ";" at onclick"sendmeback();" to get it work :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit late but remove the `";"` on `"onclick sendmeback();"` as it is causing the error and please mark the question as resolved as it makes it harder for us to find new ones!